# how to split pandas column contain list of dictionaries into keys as columns and fill the values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has a column containing a list of dictionaries.
I want to split the column into keys as columns and fill in the values

edit: every cell in the column contains a list of dictionaries, I want to split them into the same row

sample of the data:

```
[{'genre': 'Adventure, Indie, RPG',
  'item_id': '326950',
  'discounted_price': '$8.99',
  'item_url': 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/326950',
  'item_name': 'Sword of Asumi'},
 {'genre': 'Adventure, Indie, RPG',
  'item_id': '331490',
  'discounted_price': '$2.99',
  'item_url': 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/331490',
  'item_name': 'Sword of Asumi - Soundtrack'}]
```

The output that I want to be like :

| genre_0 | item_id_0 | discounted_price_0 | item_url_0 | item_name_0 | genre_1 | item_id_1 | ....etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | One | Two | Three | One | ---- |

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is every dictionary in the list a row in the expected output?

Comment: every cell  in the column contains a list of dictionaries, I want to split them into the same row

Comment: Why do you want these items on the same row? That's pretty counter to any ability to easily work with your data...

Comment: I'm working on large datasets for a recommendation system project and the data from a MongoDB database which contain five collections about the games and users and reviews

Answer (score 1):

I created a function to solve this problem

## function to split the list of dictionaries in a column

```
def split_list(df, column):
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        for i , dict_ in enumerate(row[column]):
            for key, value in dict_.items():
                df.loc[_, column + '_' + key + '_' + str(i)] = value
    # drop columns with more than 50% missing values
    df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=df.shape[0]*0.5, inplace=True)
    return df
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['data'] = [[{'genre': 'Adventure, Indie, RPG',
  'item_id': '326950',
  'discounted_price': '$8.99',
  'item_url': 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/326950',
  'item_name': 'Sword of Asumi'},
 {'genre': 'Adventure, Indie, RPG',
  'item_id': '331490',
  'discounted_price': '$2.99',
  'item_url': 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/331490',
  'item_name': 'Sword of Asumi - Soundtrack'}]]

df2 = df.copy()
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for i, dict_ in enumerate(row['data']):
        new_cols = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dict_]).rename(columns={key: f"{key}_{i}" for key in dict_.keys()})
        new_row = new_cols if i==0 else pd.concat([new_row, new_cols], axis=1)
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, new_row], axis=1)

print(df2.columns)
```

```
Index(['data', 'genre_0', 'item_id_0', 'discounted_price_0', 'item_url_0',
       'item_name_0', 'genre_1', 'item_id_1', 'discounted_price_1',
       'item_url_1', 'item_name_1'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: every cell in the column contains a list of dictionaries, I want to split them into the same row

Comment: @AhmedDaker fixed the solution. Check again!

Comment: Thanks a lot but it worked for the first row only

Comment: I added a screenshot for the output

Comment: @AhmedDaker You've used the same DataFrame `bundle_data_items` instead of both `df1` and `df2` in my code snippet. The DataFrame to which the `new_row` is appended (`df2` in my example) should be different from the one that is being iterated through using `.iterrows()`. (note `df2 = df.copy()` before the for loop as well)

Comment: I added the solution as a function to do the splitting can you check it? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) of dataframes created from list comprehension like below:

```
lst = [{'genre': 'Adventure, Indie, RPG',
  'item_id': '326950',
  'discounted_price': '$8.99',
  'item_url': 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/326950',
  'item_name': 'Sword of Asumi'},
 {'genre': 'Adventure, Indie, RPG',
  'item_id': '331490',
  'discounted_price': '$2.99',
  'item_url': 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/331490',
  'item_name': 'Sword of Asumi - Soundtrack'}]
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0]).rename(('{}_' + str(i)).format,
          axis=1) for i, d in enumerate(lst)], axis=1)
```

output:

```
                 genre_0    item_id_0   discounted_price_0                                item_url_0       item_name_0                genre_1      item_id_1    discounted_price_1  item_url_1  item_name_1
0   Adventure, Indie, RPG      326950                $8.99  http://store.steampowered.com/app/326950    Sword of Asumi  Adventure, Indie, RPG         331490                 $2.99  http://store.steampowered.com/app/331490    Sword of Asumi - Soundtrack
```